# Solve $|x - 1| + |x + 1| < 2$ algebraically.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

By drawing a number line and labeling $-1$ to $1$, it becomes apparent that there is no solution because there is no point whose distance from $-1$ and distance from $1$ sum to less than $2$. How can you use algebra to reach the same conclusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

The standard method with absolute value is to distinguish the following cases

1) $x\ge1$

$x - 1 + x + 1 < 2\implies x<1$

2) $-1\le x<1$

$-x + 1+ x + 1 < 2\implies 2<2$

3) x<-1

$-x + 1 -x -1< 2\implies x>-1$

Comment: How did you identify these three cases?

Comment: since we have |x-1| and |x+1| the key points for x are -1 and +1, thus it is convenient consider three intervals and for each one eliminate the absolute value taking the correct sign

Answer (score 5):

By the triangle inequality $$2>|x-1|+|x+1|=|x+1|+|1-x|\geq|x+1+1-x|=2,$$ which says that this inequality has no solutions.

Also, you can consider three cases:

1. $x\geq1$, which gives $x+1+x-1<2$;
2. $-1<x<1$, which gives $2<2$ and
3. $x\leq-1$, which gives $1-x-x-1<2.$

Answer (score 2):

After squaring we get $$x^2-1+|x^2-1|<0$$  Let $t=x^2-1$,  so we have $$t+|t|<0$$

So if $t>0$ we get $2t<0$. A contradiction.

If $t\leq 0$ we get $0<0$. A contradiction.

So given inequality doesn' t have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to complex numbers, draw two circles with flexible radii centered on +1 and -1 and see that if the sum of those two radiuses is smaller than 2 they will never reach each other. In fact you will by using this method also see that the closest they will get for any sum of radii is along the real axis.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a picture:

$B_1((-1,1),2) \cap \{ (x,x) \}_x = \emptyset$.

The $1$ subscript refers to the $1$-norm, $\| y\|_1 = |y_1|+|y_2|$.

**Alternative solution**: For a more analytic approach, note that $\phi(x) = |1+x|+|x-1|$ is convex and
differentiable for $|x| <1$ and $\phi'(0) = 0$, hence $0$ is a minimiser of $\phi$. 
Since $\phi(0) = 2$, we see that $\phi(x) \ge 2$ for all $x$.